# Filter out special characters from the data added to HTTP headers

Tags: java, cookies

```
Cookie[] cookies = httpServletRequest.getCookies();
String cookieStr = getCookieString(cookies);
if (cookieStr != null && !cookieStr.trim().equals("")) {
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookieStr);
```

For security reasons (in cases where data enters my application through an untrusted source), I would like to create whitelist of safe characters that are allowed to appear in HTTP response headers and accept input composed exclusively of these characters.

I am told The CR and LF characters are at the heart of an HTTP response splitting attack, as well as other characters, such as ':' (colon) and '=' (equal). Hence I would like to filter out these special characters from the data added to headers. Can anyone please suggest how I can possibly do this? I have read quite a few posts online, but I am not very clear on how I can achieve this. Please suggest.

Comment: Can someone please help me here?

Answer (score 0):

Would String methods such as indexOf() work for you?

[String api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)